# Eslint not work on vscode when format react code

Tags: javascript, reactjs, visual-studio-code, eslint

I'm trying to make ESlint work on my vscode but somehow it does not work,

I install ESlint by these step

**Step 1**

Install them by `yarn add eslint --dev`

It perform successful

**Step 2**

The setup then by `yarn create @eslint/config`
✔ How would you like to use ESLint? · problems

✔ What type of modules does your project use? · esm

✔ Which framework does your project use? · react

✔ Does your project use TypeScript? · No / Yes

✔ Where does your code run? · browser

✔ What format do you want your config file to be in? · JavaScript

The config that you've selected requires the following dependencies:

eslint-plugin-react@latest
✔ Would you like to install them now with npm? · No / Yes

I follow every step and setup and it successful too

**Step 3**

Add eslint extension on vscode,
[image]

But somehow it never work, I tried to have a file like this, but not even show an error, when I run `yarn run eslint src/App.js` (App.js) is the name, it output like this:

[image]

```
warning ../../package.json: No license field
$ /Users/khanhs/Work/React/Udacity/my-read/node_modules/.bin/eslint src/App.js
✨  Done in 0.47s
```

.

I

But the file does not get the format, so what did I do wrong here???

This project is a create react app project:

```
{
  "name": "my-read",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^5.16.4",
    "@testing-library/react": "^13.2.0",
    "@testing-library/user-event": "^13.5.0",
    "react": "^18.1.0",
    "react-dom": "^18.1.0",
    "react-scripts": "5.0.1",
    "web-vitals": "^2.1.4"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
  },
  "eslintConfig": {
    "extends": [
      "react-app",
      "react-app/jest"
    ]
  },
  "browserslist": {
    "production": [
      ">0.2%",
      "not dead",
      "not op_mini all"
    ],
    "development": [
      "last 1 chrome version",
      "last 1 firefox version",
      "last 1 safari version"
    ]
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "eslint": "^8.15.0",
    "eslint-config-react-app": "^7.0.1",
    "eslint-plugin-react": "^7.29.4"
  }
}
```

Here is `.eslintrc.js`

```
module.exports = {
    "env": {
        "browser": true,
        "es2021": true
    },
    "extends": [
        "eslint:recommended",
        "plugin:react/recommended"
    ],
    "parserOptions": {
        "ecmaFeatures": {
            "jsx": true
        },
        "ecmaVersion": "latest",
        "sourceType": "module"
    },
    "plugins": [
        "react"
    ],
    "rules": {
    }
}
```

Edit: Clearly in above App.js file, they have syntax issue, but not even show and fix it

Comment: Are you trying to use ESLint for formatting the code? Pettier is used for formatting the code

Comment: How to edit that @Pavan?

Comment: When you entered the command `yarn create @eslint/config` did you answer questions about your environment? And was an `.eslintrc.*` file created in the root of your project?

Comment: I'm voting to close. Just not enough information to answer this.

Comment: @jD3V yes, of course, i follow every step and have an .eslintrc.js file

Comment: @jD3V ,i'm not agree? which imformation you want to provide more?

Comment: I already asked for it above. You said you preformed three steps, but you didn't tell use what happened in the steps, or what happens when you try running eslint. The error message your getting says that your project doesn't even have a `package.json` file, so you must not be installing the dependancies. But there is no way of knowing, because you don't provide the information about what happens when you enter the yarn commands you said you executed.

Comment: Alright, i will update question

Answer (score -2):

- You can press the key combination `Ctr + shift + p` then input `Format document with` and select the format you want Ex: Prettier
- About eslint, it help to find problem in javascript code. You can see its full support here https://eslint.org/

Comment: This doesn't solve his/her problem. They didn't even give enough information to infer what their problem is.

Comment: Based on comments, i think he is confused about the code format with eslint. @jD3V

Comment: No, @duynguyễntích, of course i know how to do that, but it NOT format

Comment: I see your file src/app.js has no problem with eslint. You can create a variable and not use it anywhere or for sure you can add a rule then run the command yarn run eslint src/app.js again to check. You can add rule like this https://eslint.org/docs/user-guide/getting-started#configuration

Comment: Look at the format of the return html, it have format problem, i use eslint recommend, it must be something wrong

Comment: You need to change file App.js to App.jsx

Comment: Make no sense, but i tried to change it anyway, not work